# Jetty HttpParser Full

Tags: jetty

I'm getting these warnings in my log file:

```
WARN  2013-01-15 00:08:15,550 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser- HttpParser Full for SCEP@2d0a7424{l(/10.13.61.19:17602)<->r(/10.118.190.35:80),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@22e7a7e3,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-1,l=2355,c=-3},r=41} 
WARN  2013-01-15 00:08:17,275 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser- HttpParser Full for SCEP@3e428386{l(/10.13.61.19:17605)<->r(/10.118.190.35:80),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@40a77d2a,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=108,c=-3},r=57} 
WARN  2013-01-15 00:09:34,560 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser- HttpParser Full for SCEP@39c117ad{l(/10.13.61.19:17708)<->r(/10.118.190.35:80),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@11c95f6f,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-1,l=1940,c=-3},r=522} 
WARN  2013-01-15 00:09:37,185 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser- HttpParser Full for SCEP@574e9325{l(/10.13.61.19:17722)<->r(/10.118.190.35:80),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@6e997c49,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-1,l=2675,c=-3},r=101} 
WARN  2013-01-15 00:09:37,281 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser- HttpParser Full for SCEP@6838d5cb{l(/10.13.61.19:17726)<->r(/10.118.190.35:80),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@d9f6b12,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-1,l=2641,c=-3},r=4} 
WARN  2013-01-15 00:10:22,723 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser- HttpParser Full for SCEP@6f282964{l(/10.13.61.19:17805)<->r(/10.118.190.35:80),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@44627fa1,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-1,l=2211,c=-3},r=61}
```

Does anyone know what they mean or how to fix them? I'm using jetty-8.1.5.v20120716 . As you can see,  they happen very frequently.

Comment: Large cookies are frequent offenders.  Anything past 4k starts getting excessive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Translation: The request entity is too large.

Some client is issuing an excessively sized request URI + request headers.
This will result in a HTTP Response Code [`413 Request Entity Too Large`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.14) to that client.

Comment: Is there any way to see the url of the request causing this warning or any way to get more information?

Comment: Setup a Request Logger and look for entries marked with response code 413.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/RequestLog

Comment: Also know that the request header size maximum is configurable. See option 'requestHeaderSize' at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Connectors

Comment: We have a request logger configured but unfortunately requests that cause the "HttpParser Full" warning and receive a 413 don't get logged. so, does anyone have any other ideas about how to find the URL that was called? Other than tcpdump :)

Answer (score 10):

Got something similar from maven-jetty-plugin; solved by clearing all cookies for the host.

Comment: I got the same with my Jenkins plugin. Clearing cookies solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same question in solr-Query,and the reason is "the request is too long".So I add a set which name "requestHeaderSize" in **jetty.xml** then the problem is fixed . The size is depended on your demand. Hope this can help you~

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of a log message like this `(HttpParser Full)` to be related to using **Kerberos auth**.
Kerberos adds header data for each Active Directory group.
See [this Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327825) for more info.