# Jenkins new install (win8) fails to display website with HttpParser warning

Tags: jenkins

After installing Jenkins on my Win8 machine, both from the latest/greatest and from the stable  line, Jenkins fails to show the website. The logs indicate that Jenkins is running. The error log has the following data in it:

```
May 31, 2014 10:56:34 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
May 31, 2014 10:56:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
May 31, 2014 10:56:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
May 31, 2014 10:56:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
May 31, 2014 10:56:39 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
May 31, 2014 10:56:40 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
May 31, 2014 10:56:52 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: HttpParser Full for SCEP@11aee49{l(/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58237)<->r(/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@1120157,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-1,l=5755,c=-3},r=0} 
May 31, 2014 10:56:52 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: HttpParser Full for SCEP@1d5d4e5{l(/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58238)<->r(/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@18c3269,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-1,l=5841,c=-3},r=0}
```

From searching online it looks like it might be an issue with [Jetty](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-336). The issue provides states that it can be alleviated by updating some settings in the jetty configuration however I have not been able to find these in the Jenkins configuration where I'd assume they would need to be.

The question is does anybody have any suggestions on how to determine what the issue is and then on how to go about fixing it?

Comment: It seems to be related to the use of google chrome and the number of cookies that chrome sends via the http header. See: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/JIRA-core-JENKINS-23383-Console-output-live-feed-is-broken-td4705854.html

Comment: There was a question Regarding HttpParser Full (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345872/jetty-httpparser-full) It suggest that you clear your browser cookies.